# Github: readonly access to a private repo

Tags: git, github, collaboration, readonly, public-key

I am developing some private projects on Github, and I would like to add nightly cronjobs to my deployments servers to pull the latest version from github. I am currently doing this by generating keypairs on every deployment server and adding the public key to the github project as 'Deployment key'.

However, I recently found out that these deployment keys actually do have write access to the project. Hence, every of the server administrators could potentially start editing. Furthermore I can add every deployment key to only one repository, whereas I would like to be able to deploy multiple repositories on one and the same deployment server.

Is there a way to provide read-only access for private repositories to selected users on Github?

Comment: You want to have *restricted* **read only** access, isn't it?  If you want *unrestricted* read-only access, you can use `git://` protocol instead of `ssh://` (`ssh+git://`).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I [have it on good authority](https://twitter.com/defunkt/status/1678391086419969) that the (relatively new) ["Organizations"](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations) feature allows you to add people with read-only access to a private repository.

Comment: That is actually a workaround as you need to create a personal account. They could've designed this better by allowing the creation of API tokens per organization with rights thus eliminating the workaround to either compromise a team member's account or to create a fake personal account.

Comment: Too bad you've got to pay $25/mo for that feature. For a small site, that $300/yr can pay for a lot of hosting elsewhere. Thanks @Trindaz

Comment: That's why BitBucket is not a second fiddle to Github.

Comment: This answer is outdated. See the answer on read-only deploy keys.

Answer (score 52):

For anyone else finding this question, know that nowadays you can in fact create read-only deploy keys:

https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys

You can still create deploy keys with write access, but have to explicitly grant that permission when adding the key.

Comment: Unfortunately deploy keys can be used only for SSH access.

Answer (score 3):

I know that the questions is about github but maybe for some readers it would be nice to know that this is possible in gitlab and for free. Check https://gitlab.com/help/user/permissions. I spend some time using github without fully serving my purposes. If I knew then I would have started this particular project with gitlab.

Answer (score 2):

For Organizations:
I suggest creating a new team specifically for the user. This team can then grant read-only access to the repositories you specify. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for GitHub on 2023-12-26:

```
git clone https://myusername:github_pat_11AAJ3xxxxx@github.com/myusername/myproject.git
```

Where:

- `myusername` is your GitHub username
- `myproject` is the Git project name.
- `github_pat_11AAJ3xxxxx` is the access token.

To generate the access token:

- In GitHub, click on profile picture (top right) then `[ Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens > Fine Grained Tokens ]`.
- Then click on `Generate New Token`, select `Only select repositories` and choose the private repositories you want to grant read-only access to.
- Under Repository permissions, ensure `Read access` to `"actions, administration, code, codespaces, and metadata"`.
- Copy the resultant token to the clipboard.