# Enabling other github users to only fork my private repository and send me pull requests

Tags: git, version-control, github

Is that make sense to enable other **GitHub** users to only **fork** my private repository and send me **pull requests**. I don't want them to push changes directly to my private repo.

What I am struggling here is that a user cannot see my private repo which is a good thing. Then, I add the user as collaborator to my repo and that user now has push access to that private repo which is a bad thing.

It would also work for me if there is chance to give a user only access to specific branches for my private repo.

Any thought on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github: readonly access to a private repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868432/github-readonly-access-to-a-private-repo)

Comment: @huitseeker hmm, so I need an organization account. Did I get that correct?

Comment: I don't think github allows such fine-grained access. gitolite, however, does.

Comment: I think the same goes for bitbucket which has free private repos but with limited partners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need an "organisation" plan for your account to do that. If you have an organisation, you can define teams. Teams can different privileges for repos like read-only. You would need to set up two teams and two repos. Your base repo would have one team only being able to read it, but not write to it. The child repo would have both teams with read access to it.

I'm not aware that something like that is possible with the commercial but non-organisation account plans.