# git maintaining 2 versions of the same project, with different users on each

Tags: git, github

I have a (private) project in github where a team of developers commits changes. A client has now asked to develop some heavy customizations on their own copy of the system. A new team will be working on this project, but I don't want this team to have access to the original repository. So I created a new repository on github, and initialized it with the code from the original project.

However, I still want the 2nd project to get the updates done on the original project. How can I setup the repositories to meet this need?

Alternatively, if I am to keep a single project, is there a way to have the new team only access a specific branch on it?

Comment: They need to have access to the original repository in some way. I think what you mean is they need to have read-only access. Presumably this is a private repository, otherwise the question wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: yes, this is a private repo. I don't want them to have access to the original project, even read-only, as it contains other data (some additional files, branches) that are not related to the code they have access to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have followed the recommendation on [this site](http://eatmyrandom.blogspot.gr/2009/07/how-to-merge-two-independent-git.html). I'm repeating the process here for anyone interested:
Let's assume that the original project is checked out in **projectA** and the derived project in **projectB**:

The first time I did:

```
 cd path/to/projectB
 git remote add orig_project path/to/projectA 
 git fetch orig_project
 git merge orig_project/master -X theirs
 git push
```

Now every time I need to synchronize changes from projectA to projectB, I do:

```
git fetch orig_project
git merge orig_project/master
git push
```

`orig_project` can be anything. I used `-X theirs` the first time, because otherwise all fetched changes conflicted

Answer (score 1):

Take the other data out of the repository. Make a new repository with only the files and branches you want them to be able to see, and delete them from the old repository. Then [give them read-only access to the new repository.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868432/github-readonly-access-to-a-private-repo)

Comment: This is indeed a viable alternative, I'll consider it

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called branch (and i see that you using it).

https://help.github.com/articles/branching-out
http://learn.github.com/p/branching.html

Once you have the branches you dont need a new codebase, you can use fork (Tell them to for you project) and this way they can get updates

Read mroe here:
[Definition of "downstream" and "upstream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream)

Comment: And how can I prevent the 2nd team from accessing the original codebase? I want them to have access to a single branch of the project