# How to set up github readonly access

Tags: github

I have a private repo at github and the access is controlled by deployment ssh key pairs. Now I want to set up a read-only access for CI.

I searched this: 
    [Github: readonly access to a private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868432/github-readonly-access-to-a-private-repo)

but still clueless.

Anybody can let me know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for [GitHub deploy keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys). See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository) for more detail.

Comment: Doing this gives R/W permissions. Any way to grant read-only access?

Comment: @user2777473 currently I see no way to get a "read only" deploy key.. sounds like they do not currently exist on Github.

Comment: Now they do!  [https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys](https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys)

Answer (score 4):

Go to `https://github.com/organizations/<your organisation>/teams`, there you can create a read-only access team for your repository.

The difficulty of finding this page surprises me every time I need it.

Comment: The repo is not an organization. and none of the team members has github accounts. :-( We are distributing SSH keys for the access.